# Refactor ruby code based on the admin present or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I want to refactor this code:

```
def self.find_posts(page, per_page, author_id, user)
  if user.admin?
    paginate(page: page, per_page: per_page)  #fetches on the basis of per_page
  else
    paginate(page: page, per_page: per_page).where(author: author_id) #Based on author_id
  end
end
```

`Post.paginate(page: page, per_page: per_page)` is repeated two times so I wanted to remove it.

Here is what I tried:

```
def self.find_posts(page, per_page, author_id, user)
  paginate(page: page, per_page: per_page)  #fetches the no of per_page
  if user.admin?
    #not getting what should I write here
  else
    where(author: author_id) #Based on author_id
  end
end
```

This code also doesn't work which I know that `paginate` is not the last sentence. I could use `return` there but somehow I'm not understanding how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't beg for help. Stack Overflow exists to help people. Thanking us isn't necessary either, as SO is not a discussion forum, it's more of a reference book where you're helping write articles on fixing specific programming problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it is necessary to refactor it. But just to give you options :

You could do this (or build the hash before)

```
paginate(page: page, per_page: per_page).where(user.admin? ? {} : {author: author_id})
```

or add a default scope to your post

Comment: or `(user.admin? ? all : where(author: author_id)).paginate(page: page) `

Comment: Good approach but scoping it is not very useful for me as i don't need to use it again

Comment: Ternary operator as method parameter in where is just unreadably and ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write:

```
def self.find_posts(page, per_page, author_id, user)
  posts = user.admin? ? Post.all : Post.where(author: author_id) 
  posts.paginate(page: page, per_page: per_page)
end
```

Comment: Also bare in mind that in ActiveRecord class-level method can be chained with scopes. This together with scopes from pundit gem (access authorization) can give you really clean solution. Take a look https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes

Comment: tokland: I have a doubt here. It will fetch `all` posts here and then it will paginate it, which i need to avoid. I dont at all want to fetch all records at a time.

Comment: No, only very old versions of ActiveRecord fetched greedily all records as an array. Now `all` is a lazy operation and returns a `Relation` that can be used in scopes.